# Simplify expression, algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\;\sqrt[n]{\frac{600}{25^{n+2}-5^{2n+2}}}\;$$
 I 
must simplify this expression but I don't know how to do it. The answer is: $5^{-2}$

Comment: Your expression isn't clear. After almost 40 days being a member and sending 6 questions, it's about time you learn how to properly writhe mathematics in this site.

Comment: @DonAntonio  \nrt means n√(...) But I don't know how to write in the right way

Comment: Do you mean the $\;n\,-$ th root? Like $\;\sqrt[n] x\;$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio done, thanks, man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $25^{n+2}-5^{2n+2}=5^{2n+2}(25-1)$

If this is at first not evident, consider the following:

If you want to convert $25^{n+2}$ to some exponent of $5$, then:

$$5^x=25^{n+2}\Rightarrow log(5^x)=log(25^{n+2})\Rightarrow x=(n+2)\frac {log(25)}{log(5)}=2(n+2)=2n+4$$

So we see,

$$5^{2n+4}=25^{n+2}$$

So considering your question:

$$^n\sqrt {\frac {600}{25^{n+2}-5^{2n+2}}}=^n\sqrt {\frac {600}{5^{2n+4}-{5^{2n+2}}}}=^n\sqrt {\frac {5^2\cdot 24}{5^{2n+2}({25-1)}}}=^n\sqrt {\frac {24}{5^{2n}{(24)}}}=^n\sqrt {\frac {1}{5^{2n}}}=5^{-2}$$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57281/discussion-on-answer-by-mark-pineau-simplify-expression-algebra).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

$$25^{n+2}-5^{2n+2}=5^{2n+2}\left(25-1\right)$$

whereas

$$600=24\cdot5^2$$